# How to convert code to a list comprehension

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to rewrite the code below as a list comprehension, but the line - `if groceries[k] == v and k not in most_needed' - does not work as desired. It generates an error msg that most_needed is not identified and when it's declared, the code produces duplicates when the values are the same - e.g. two pastas and two salsas. The output is a sorted list of items with the keys of the values printed in reverse order. Can someone advise how to correct? Thanks.

```
groceries = {'apples': 5, 'pasta': 3, 'carrots': 12, 'orange juice': 2, 'bananas': 8,   
            'popcorn': 1, 'salsa': 3, 'cereal': 4, 'coffee': 5, 'granola bars': 15,  
            'onions': 7, 'rice': 1, 'peanut butter': 2, 'spinach': 9}
most_needed = []  

for v in sorted(groceries.values(), reverse=True):
    for k in groceries:
        if groceries[k] == v and k not in most_needed:
            most_needed.append(k)
            break
print(', '.join(most_needed) + '.')

# prints --> granola bars, carrots, spinach, bananas, onions, coffee, apples, cereal, 
  salsa, pasta, peanut butter, orange juice, rice, popcorn 

most_needed = [k for v in sorted(groceries.values(), reverse=True) for k in groceries
               if groceries[k] == v and k not in most_needed]
```

Comment: you can't use a list comprehension in this case.

Comment: I copy&pasted your code verbatim as-is and executed it with python3 and I do not get any error (the resulting list is empty, but there is no error). Please show us the exact code you are trying to run (and specify the exact python version if that matters – I'm assuming python 3, because python 2 has been EOL for quite some time; but even with python 2, the code produces no error)

Comment: you cannot check the values of your list comprehension as you build it ... it is not possible ... you could have a seperate set that you are tracking but that will complicate your list comprehension ... even if you could check the values of most_needed while you iterated over it, this ends up being very slow as you are iterating several times over the dictionary and sorting it and then searching a list over and over

Comment: This is the output. Note the duplicates! granola bars, carrots, spinach, bananas, onions, apples, coffee, apples, coffee, cereal, pasta, salsa, pasta, salsa, orange juice, peanut butter, orange juice, peanut butter, popcorn, rice, popcorn, rice.

Comment: Consider using `collections.Counter.most_common`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are overcomplicating things

```
groceries = {'apples': 5, 'pasta': 3, 'carrots': 12, 'orange juice': 2, 'bananas': 8,   
            'popcorn': 1, 'salsa': 3, 'cereal': 4, 'coffee': 5, 'granola bars': 15,  
            'onions': 7, 'rice': 1, 'peanut butter': 2, 'spinach': 9}

most_needed = sorted(groceries.keys(),key=lambda x: groceries[x], reverse=True)
```